# Solr4 max() function seems to lose precision on TrieDateField values

Tags: datetime, solr, solr4

I have documents that have two date fields, "published_date" and "updated_date". The updated_date field is empty until an update occurs. After there has been an update, I would like to use updated_date as the field to sort by. This is not the exact situation but close enough, and index a single correct field is the least desirable solution.

So I'm trying to do "sort=max(published_date, updated_date) desc"

To validate the results I have "fl=max_date:max(published_date, updated_date), published_date, updated_date"

What I'm seeing is this:

```
  "docs": [
  {
    "max_date": 1409953170000,
    "published_date": "2014-09-05T21:39:01.322Z",
    "updated_date": "2014-09-05T21:39:01.319Z"
  },
  {
    "max_date": 1409953040000,
    "published_date": "2014-09-05T21:36:51.614Z",
    "updated_date": "2014-09-05T21:36:51.611Z"
  },
  {
    "max_date": 1409953040000,
    "published_date": "2014-09-05T21:38:01.111Z",
    "updated_date": "2014-09-05T21:38:01.107Z"
  },
  {
    "max_date": 1409953040000,
    "published_date": "2014-09-05T21:38:11.151Z",
    "updated_date": "2014-09-05T21:38:11.148Z"
  },
  {
    "max_date": 1409953040000,
    "published_date": "2014-09-05T21:37:36.202Z",
    "updated_date": "2014-09-05T21:37:36.194Z"
  },
  {
    "max_date": 1409953040000,
    "published_date": "2014-09-05T21:37:41.92Z",
    "updated_date": "2014-09-05T21:37:41.915Z"
  }, ...
```

So you can see the max_date that is being sorted by Does not have the same precision as the underlying timestamps. The results are out of order, and the result from max() clearly has room for more precision as it always ends with four zeros.

So how do I make this work? Or is there a bug in solr's conversion functions?

UPDATE:

So it seems from: lucene-solr-lucene_solr_4_5_0/lucene/queries/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queries/function/valuesource/MaxFloatFunction.java

That shows max() is implemented by casting it's arguments to floatVal, since dates are stored as Longs in a TrieField clearly precision is being lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened a bug with SOLR to address the issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6490

Answer (score 0):

Trie*-fields have [their precision set by using `precisionStep` on the field](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieField.html). That way you can get the precision you need for the specific usage. Using `64` as `precisionStep` will in effect make the field a regular long/Date-field, where you'll have only the exact value available in your function queries (as Trie-fields index several tokens otherwise, to make the fast range search work).

Changing this will however not make the field any faster for range queries, so you might want to have one field for sorting and one for range queries (if needed).

Comment: How can i convince it to use the full precision token in the sort function? My understanding of precisionStep, was it was the number of bits dropped for each level of tokens.

This patch: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12471282/SOLR-2371.patch makes it seem like the field would be cast to a Double when used in max(), so I'd expect full precision.

Certainly I have the precision as the dates are accurate when displayed. I tried max(ms(pub), ms(update)) but that was just slower for the same result. adding ms(pub) to fl= displays as a date not integer, surprisingly.